# Apostrophe s and parentheses in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am concatenating two columns in postgreSQL and do not know how to get this task done. I want to be able to get the "Lot_Size" in parentheses and add a apostrophe s with the numbers.

```
select concat("Builder",' ', "Lot_Size") as "NewColumn" from MyTable

NewColumn
Macys 55
Blue Goose 65
Blue Mesa 75
```

The result I am trying to get:

```
Macys (55's)
Blue Goose (65's)
Blue Mesa (75's)
```

Comment: Try `SELECT "Builder" || ' (' || "Lot_Size" || '''s)' As NewColumn FROM MyTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. To concatenate `'` you have to use `''`.

```
select "Builder" ||' ('|| "Lot_Size" || '''s)' as "NewColumn" from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a good time to use dollar quoting.

```
select "Builder" ||  ' (' || "Lot_Size" || $$'s)$$ as "NewColumn" from MyTable;
```

I find that this makes the embedded quoting a little easier to read.